# Django: how to chain 2 add() calls in 1 create()?

Tags: python, django

```
class District(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    transports = models.ManyToManyField(TransportWay)
    schools = models.ManyToManyField(School)
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
District.objects.create(name="Arc de Triomphe")\
        .transports.add(tr_m1, tr_m2)\
        .schools.add(sc_dauph)
```

It does not work since `District.objects.create(name="Arc de Triomphe").transports.add(tr_m1, tr_m2)`returns `None` (but it works) instead of the District object.

Do you know any solution to make it in one call? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you need it to have it in one call?

Comment: Some kind of this possible when you have only one `ManyToManyField` - then simply create `through` model object

Comment: @omeinusch It's because I'm using this for dabatase fixtures, I create lots of objects. It would be simpler to write and read if I would not have to create a variable and several lines for each objects created. But it's not critical as well :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of SQL queries, there isn't any benefit of doing the first chaining,

```
District.objects.create(name="Arc de Triomphe")\
    .transports.add(tr_m1, tr_m2)
```

as it uses just as many queries.

So you might as well do it the long way.

```
district = District.objects.create(name="Arc de Triomphe")\
district.transports.add(tr_m1, tr_m2)
district.schools.add(sc_dauph)
```

If you're worried about transactions, then use the [`atomic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) decorator.

If your concern is readability, then I don't think it's worth worrying about. Hacking `add()` to return the object you are adding to would be surprising to other users, who will expect it to return `None`. If you're using `\` for line breaks, then it uses just as many lines of code as assigning the created object to another variable.

If you're really worried about repetition, then you can create a helper function, e.g. `create_district`, then call it as follows:

```
create_district(
    name="Arc de Triomphe",
    transports=[tr_m1, tr_m2],
    schools=[sc_dauph],
)
```